# How can I insert date from <p:calendar> into mysql database in Primefaces via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, javabeans

I have a problem about inserting date selected in Calendar into the mysql database. I can select any date from calendar but I don't know how to do the process of insertation. All process is done by Hibernate

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Here is my Person Class

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthDate;
```

Here is my xhtml file

```
<h:form>
....
<p:outputLabel value="Birth Date:"/>
                <p:calendar value="#{personManaged.person.birthDate}" locale="tr" 
                            yearRange="c-70:c+10" navigator="true" mask="true" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
....

<p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="false" 
                                                action="#{personManaged.savePersonManagedToDatabase}"/>
</h:form>
```

Here is my bean class

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class personManaged {


}
```

Comment: You should write your attempts to solve the issue, after give as your code and try to ask a question with a good precession. This is a malformed question.

Comment: Same ways you would for a plain string or a number or a boolean or...Narrow down the problem. Can you submit a value from the client to the server, then JSF is working and it is not jsf/PrimeFaces related. If that fails, it is a pure jsf thing and not hibernate related.